# drop down elements getting hidden !!! z-index Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="LangCtrl" class="dropdown dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="true" style="cursor:pointer;"> 
   {{'COMMON.CHOOSE_LANG' | translate}} 
   <span class="caret"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li ng-repeat="lang in langs" ng-click="changeLanguage(lang.key)" id="lang_{{lang.key}}"><a href="">{{lang.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

I tried to change the z-index value for the dropdown menu but nothing gets worked out.I don't know where is the problem. There are four languages in the dropdown ,but two are getting hidden.

I have attached the CSS and HTML above. Please help me.
Any help is appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a live version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without all the code stack I can't be sure, but could you please check that this issue is not caused by an `overflow: hidden` into your container ?

Also, note that only positionned elements are affected by the z-index stack.